# How to make MacBook automatically connect to different wifi networks as desired?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, network, wifi

My main router is located in the living room and creates a wifi hotspot, call it X. I've created an additional wifi hotspot in my bedroom, call it Y, using two powerline adaptors.

How do I make my MacBook automatically connect to X while I'm in the living room and to Y while I'm in the bedroom. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

OS X will connect to the Wi-Fi network with the strongest signal, although it won't switch immediately between networks to avoid disruption to the connection.

You can alleviate this by **having the same SSID for both networks**, which will cause OS X to see them as a single network and switch between them automatically.

Comment: This answer is not correct. OSX is notoriously bad for sticking with a network until the bitter end.

See this much more thorough response to a similar question: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/178985/how-to-get-osx-to-pick-the-strongest-wifi-signal-with-identical-ssids